# What are the different currency types?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I would like to know more about the different kinds of currency in World of Warcraft.

Can anyone please tell me what the different types of currency are and what they're used for?

Comment: Have you ever considered asking in channel /1 (General) or /4 (LFG)?

Comment: are we really advising that somebody who has come to us with a valid question goes off to the game and chats in trade chat or general chat to get their answer?

Comment: @kalina Considering the community has decided to close his "valid" questions on numerous occasions, why not?

Comment: The edits to this question make some hefty assumptions on what he was asking, for all we know he could have been asking about gold, silver and bronze or whatever the coins are these days

Comment: No assumptions were made. See the question I linked in my edit description

Comment: This is a nice question to have here. The problem with in-game chat is that YMMV depending on what's going on at the time. Unfortunately, the only problem with this question is that the answer changes with each expansion.

Answer (score 15):

There are multiple types of currency available in World of Warcraft, in addition to gold. Each currency is earned a different way.

## Current currencies

This section deals with currencies that are "current" as of the latest expansion - Mists of Pandaria.

#### Gold

Gold is the primary currency used for buying items from most vendors and from the auction house. Gold is tradable with other players in game through the trade window and can be mailed to other players by using a mailbox. Gold is earned by killing enemies, selling items, etc.

For more information on how to get lots of gold, see [How can I earn lots of gold?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/how-can-i-earn-lots-of-gold)

#### PvE points (Justice and Valor)

Player vs Environment points are split into Justice points and Valor points. These points are earned by killing bosses in dungeons, raids, and as a reward for using the dungeon and raid finder. These points can be spent at Justice and Valor vendors for relatively high end PvE gear.

#### PvP points (Honour and Conquest)

Player vs Player points are split into Honour and Conquest points. These points are earned by killing players in battlegrounds, arenas, and cities belonging to the other faction. These points can be spent at Honour and Conquest vendors for relatively high end PvP gear with resilience on it.

#### Questing currencies

**Darkmoon tokens** are earned by taking part in the Darkmoon Faire and can be used to purchase items from Darkmoon Faire vendors.

**Lesser charms of good fortune** are earned by completing Mists of Pandaria daily questions and used to purchase Elder charms of good fortune.

**Elder charms of good fortune** are used to "re-roll" on items that drop in Mists of Pandaria raids, to provide you more opportunities to get epic loot from Tier 14 bosses.

**Timeless coins** are earned from completing quests on Timeless Isle and are used for the purchase of relatively high end epic gear.

**Mogu Rune of Fate** are purchased using Timeless coins and are used to "re-roll" on items that drop in Mists of Pandaria raids, to provide you more opportunities to get epic loot from Tier 15 bosses.

## Notable currencies from past expansions

**Tol Barad Commendations** area earned by completing daily quests and the Tol Barad PvP map and can be used to purchase a variety of items including low level items for level 85 characters, mounts and pets.

**Marks of the World Tree** are tokens earned by completing Molton Front daily quests and are used to purchase items and to progress through the Molton Front story line.

**Mote of Darkness** are tokens earned by killing bosses in the Dragon Soul raid, used for purchasing crystalline geodes (which contain high end Cataclsym gems).

**Essence of Corrupted Deathwing** are tokens earned by killing Deathwing in the Dragon Soul raid, used for purchasing elementium-coated geodes (which contain high end Cataclysm gems).

**Illustrious Jewelcrafter's Token** are tokens earned by completing jewelcrafting daily quests in your faction's capital city, used for purchasing Cataclysm jewelcrafting recipes.

**Dalaran Jewelcrafter's Token** are tokens earned by completing Dalarn jewelcrafting daily quests in Dalan, used for purchasing Wrath of the Lich King jewelcrafting recipes.

**Champion's Seal** are tokens earned and spent at the Argent Tournament grounds.

Answer (score 4):

Money, is really purely gold, silver, and copper.  There are, however, different forms of currency - Lesser Charms, Mogu Runes of Fate, Honor Points, Valor Points, etc.

So it depends on what type of 'money' you are referring to.  If money, then the gold; otherwise there are quite a few different currencies within the game.

Comment: Now I'm curious, why the downvote?  Is it because of a poorly phrased question, or because of the answer itself?

Comment: Additionally, [here's a current full list of all of the different kinds of non-gold currencies available in the game](http://wowhead.com/currencies).

Comment: @Jon I'm guessing it's because of the answer, at least it should be. Downvoting an answer just because it happens to be on a bad question is not good practice.

Comment: @Nolonar I agree with the latter being bad practice.  Though with other SE sites I am on, someone will leave a helpful comment as to why they think the answer is bad. I'm new to this particular site, so I was curious.